# Не запускается self-contained приложение Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, развертывание

Я разрабатываю self-contained приложение (автономное развертывание) на Asp.NET Core 2.1, предназначенное для запуска на сервере с ОС Debian 8 Jessie.

Выполняю сборку командой

> dotnet publish -r debian.8-x64 -c Release

В рузультате сборки получаю папку с файлами приложения `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/debian.8-x64/`

При попытке запуска на Debian Jessie получаю такую ошибку:

> Error:
>     An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (App.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'MessagePack', version: '1.7.3.4'
>       path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/MessagePack.dll'

Пробовал добавлять ключ **--force** при сборке проекта, изменять целевую платформу на **linux-x64**, добавлять ссылку на netstandard в .csproj, но ни один вариант не помог.

Comment: какой командой запускал?

Comment: возможно [это поможет](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542)

Comment: Не, добавление строки **<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>** не помогло, да и даунгрейд тут не вариант, там как я понял у них идет речь о зависимом от платформы развертывании, в процессе апгрейда. Но все равно спасибо за помощь.

Comment: там еще было про установку sdk и самой среды(dotnet в смысле), возможно надо поставить sdk если его еще нет

Comment: В моем случае очень не желательно что либо устанавливать на сервер, поэтому и возникла необходимость собрать self-contained приложение, чтобы сама среда исполнения была включена в состав сборки с приложением.

Comment: А разве `dotnet publish -r debian.8-x64 -c Release` соберет именно такое приложение?

Comment: Да, сейчас там если указана платформа, под которую собирается приложение, оно по умолчанию становится автономным.

Comment: А зависимые библиотеки добавляются? Возможно стоит посмотреть в этом направлении

Comment: Как я понял да, в папке publish приложения лежит и файл MessagePack.dll и netstandard.dll. Да и в .csproj пробовал явно указывать ссылку на netstandard, но ошибка остается.